# displaying all categories/terms applicable to single page in javo directory

Tags: php, taxonomy-terms

I am using javo directory theme and I cannot seem to figure this out. On the map page where there are a list of listings (after user does a search by category). However, only the first category is being displayed and I need all the categories of each listing to be displayed. Displaying only 1 category defeats the purpose of being able to search by category. Here is the code, let me know if you need other code to better understand what I am trying to do but I know the change has to be within this area. I have looked everywhere for a solution which is why I need some help Thanks a lot!

```
public function get_meta( $key, $default_value=false ) {
    $strOutput  = get_post_meta( $this->post_id, $key, true );
    return empty( $strOutput ) ? $default_value : $strOutput;
}

public function m( $key, $value=false ){
    return $this->get_meta( $key, $value );
}

public function get_term( $taxonomy=false, $sep=', ' )
{
    $output_terms = Array();
    if( $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $this->post_id, $taxonomy, Array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) )
    {
        $output_terms = is_array( $terms ) ? join( $sep, $terms ) : null;
        $output_terms = trim( $output_terms );
        // $output_terms = substr( $output_terms, 0, -1 );
    }else{
        $output_terms = '';
    }
    return $output_terms;
}

public function c( $taxonomy=false, $default='',  $single=true, $sep=', ' )
{
    $strTerms   = $this->get_term( $taxonomy, $sep );

    if( $single && !empty( $strTerms  ) ) {
        $strTerms   = @explode( $sep, $strTerms );
        $strTerms   = isset( $strTerms[0] ) ? $strTerms[0] : '' ;
    }
    return empty( $strTerms ) ? $default : $strTerms;
}

public function category() {
    return $this->c(
        apply_filters( 'jvfrm_spot_' . get_class( $this ) . '_featured_tax', 'category', $this->post_id ),
        apply_filters( 'jvfrm_spot_' . get_class( $this ) . '_featured_no_tax', __( "No Category", 'javo' ), $this->post_id )
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you trim this down to a more Minimal [MCVE]?

Comment: Sorry it is just I am unsure of where exactly the problem is occurring but here is a smaller section of the code which I believe is causing the issue: